# Ruby CGI::Cookie raw cookie parsing

Tags: ruby, cookies, cgi, ruby-1.9.3

I want to be able to parse raw cookie strings in ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0].

The [CGI::Cookie](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Cookie.html) library looked promising, however, it does not work how I thought it might have.

For example,

```
CGI::Cookie::parse("ASPSESSIONIDSCDRSRTS=HHALOHOBJGJMLPIANNLDOMCJ; path=/").each_key {|name| p 'Cookie name: ' + name}
```

Will return:

```
"Cookie name: ASPSESSIONIDSCDRSRTS"
"Cookie name: path"
```

What I would like is something like the `CGI::new` instance works, except you pass it a raw cookie string:

```
cookie1 = CGI::Cookie::new('name'    => 'name',
                       'value'   => ['value1', 'value2', ...],
                       'path'    => 'path',   # optional
                       'domain'  => 'domain', # optional
                       'expires' => Time.now, # optional
                       'secure'  => true      # optional
                      )

name    = cookie1.name
values  = cookie1.value
path    = cookie1.path
domain  = cookie1.domain
expires = cookie1.expires
secure  = cookie1.secure
```

What I can't figure out is how to do this eloquently from a raw cookie string.

EDIT ---

The following code is in the `~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/cgi/cookie.rb` file. So it should return as commented below `cookies[name] = Cookie::new(name, *values)`. Which I on't seem to be getting.

```
# Parse a raw cookie string into a hash of cookie-name=>Cookie
# pairs.
#
#   cookies = CGI::Cookie::parse("raw_cookie_string")
#     # { "name1" => cookie1, "name2" => cookie2, ... }
#
def Cookie::parse(raw_cookie)
  cookies = Hash.new([])
  return cookies unless raw_cookie

  raw_cookie.split(/[;,]\s?/).each do |pairs|
    name, values = pairs.split('=',2)
    next unless name and values
    name = CGI::unescape(name)
    values ||= ""
    values = values.split('&').collect{|v| CGI::unescape(v,@@accept_charset) }
    if cookies.has_key?(name)
      values = cookies[name].value + values
    end
    cookies[name] = Cookie::new(name, *values)
  end

  cookies
end
```

EDIT ---

This seems to be a bug in Ruby's `CGI::Cookie.parse` method. I've opened a bug report on the Ruby bug tracker - https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7364

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same problem. `CGI::Cookie.new` is just not capable to consume what `CGI::Cookie::parse` produces, they just don't seem to complement each other the way we expected then.

Searching through the gems quickly I found https://github.com/dwaite/cookiejar . It seems this gem tries to do a lot, but least it has code to properly parse raw cookies as we expect it. I didn't try to understand the library because it seems it does so much stuff and I'm actually only concerned about "consuming cookie -> modiyfing it -> produces cookie".

I came up with this quick hack:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'cookiejar'

# Some sample
raw_cookie = "somecookie=some%7Cvalue; expires=Wed, 02 Apr 2014 13:36:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.somedomain.com"

parts = CookieJar::CookieValidation.parse_set_cookie raw_cookie
# Needs manual unescape
parts[:value] = CGI::unescape(parts[:value])
# Per spec, this name is different
parts[:expires] = parts[:expires_at]
# Remove old ones
parts.delete :expires_at
# CookieJar adds them always, remove
parts.delete :version
# Convert symbol keys to strings for GGI::Cookie
cookie = parts.inject(Hash.new) do |acc, (k,v)|
  acc[k.to_s] = v 
  acc 
end
puts CGI::Cookie.new(cookie).to_s
#=> somecookie=some%7Cvalue; domain=.somedomain.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 02 Apr 2014 13:36:50 GMT
```

I guess that should be a call for a gem which does only one thing with cookies and does it well: being able to parse and generate raw cookie strings. But TBH, the problem domain is probably much more complex then fooling around the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the library, but according to the Ruby docs ( http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Cookie.html ) what you're calling |name| in your block is actually a Cookie object.

```
parse(raw_cookie) 
Parse a raw cookie string into a hash of cookie-name=>Cookie pairs.
```

You're probably just seeing the name printed out as that's what an implicit .to_s will give you on a Cookie.

Try printing name.path or name.value (or any of the accessors of a Cookie object) instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. ```CGI::Cookie::parse(cookie).each_key {|cookie| p cookie.name}``` gives a 'undefined method `name' for "ASPSESSIONIDSCDRSRTS":String error. But it is the kind of thing I would like to do.

Comment: ```CGI::Cookie::parse("ASPSESSIONIDSCDRSRTS=HHALOHOBJGJMLPIANNLDOMCJ; path=/")``` returns ```{"ASPSESSIONIDSCDRSRTS"=>["ABELOHOBLLPBBABHPIGJACJL"], "path"=>["/"]}``` which I think makes the documentation wrong?

Comment: What happens if you go the other way and create a cookie with the values you're after? (passing a hash into the new function)? What does the string representation look like? (using my_cookie.to_s)

Then try going the other way, see if it's the documentation or the data.

Comment: It seems that this line ```raw_cookie.split(/[;,]\s?/).each do |pairs|``` is splitting the raw cookie string into name/value pairs. However, what it is doing is splitting ```path=/``` into a name/value pair thinking that it is a cookie name/value.

Comment: This seems to be a bug, I've opened a bug report - https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7364

Comment: So, the fix was rejected. Shouldn't cookie parsing be part of the core library?